# How do I make the width of each character the same?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I'm using a custom font. The design doesn't allow me to change font.

While the number change, the content after it got pushed around due to the different width of digits.

Is there a way to make all the digits same width? I don't want to assign the width of the `span` component because I need this to be inline and the width should be determined by the number of digits it has.

```js
const numberDom = document.querySelector('.number');
let number = 0;

function tick() {
  number += 1;
  numberDom.innerText = number;
}

setInterval(tick, 50);
```

```css
p {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

.number {
  font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  color: #365;
}

.number::after {
  content: 'pt';
  font-size: 0.75em;
  margin-left: 0.1em;
  color: #587;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<p>You got <span class="number"></span>, good job!</p>
```

Comment: If you don't want to put it inside a `span` tag you could use a Monospace font from Google: https://fonts.google.com/?category=Monospace

Comment: That's the problem, I can't use another font because the font is pre-determined. So is there a way to make a non-mono font look mono?

Comment: Not that I know. Just using monospace fonts or using the `span` to customise each character. Fonts are created using Fontforge or other graphic Design tools with their own font kerning and it can't be changed by CSS / JS / ....

Comment: @HaoWu something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/ms58q39k/)?

Comment: @xmaster Seems still the same from here, the `good job` is still jiggling while the last digit changes :S

Comment: @HaoWu what do you mean it's still the same? Because it works perfectly for me

Comment: @xmaster I'm not sure what you did but you changed my font... and the jiggling issue is still there :S [Like this](https://i.imgur.com/T7jF0Xx.gif)

Comment: @HaoWu ah okay now i understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so first I made a function that it changes the looks of your `<p>`. after that the only solution I could find to stop the jiggling was to put the number in an `inline-block`.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xghfy9sq/)

**Edit**

I made a script that changes the `width` of the `inline-block`. It's an if statement that if your number is 1000 or higher the `width` will change.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vj4yzgqL/)

You can always make an `else if` with over 10000 et cetera.

Comment: Thanks, I forked your fiddle and I think by doing it this way is a little bit cleaner :) https://jsfiddle.net/wheatup/s2b50ptc/6/

Answer (score 2):

Change your number class as:

```
.number {
    font-family: 'Carter One', cursive;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    color: #365;
    width: 56px;
    display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Still kinda weird when it's getting longer :/, maybe I need to break each letter into inline-blocks and manually set each digits' width to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
.numbers{
 font-family: Tahoma;
}
```

It will fix the number jumping/height abnormality issue.
Use any monospace font as font-family and you will fix the issue.